# API Cursor Based Pagination with Curl

Tags: rest, curl, pagination

Currently I'm working on a project for university. The goal is to make API calls with cmd (Curl) and transfer the data into a BI tool. I don't have any experience with coding/scripting and so on. The problem I currently have is that a single API call brings back 100 resources but I need all of the Data to visualize it.

`curl -X get "https://(url)" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: Basic (Username:Password) --proxy () --output () --output-dir ()`

So my goal here is to create like a loop so that all of the data is getting saved in one file.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Either it is in the API documentation how to get all the pages or there are Range headers or there are Link headers or hyperlinks attached to the response body for the next/previous pages or there is a MIME type e.g. JSON-LD, HTML, XML, etc. you can request with Accept header which contains hyperlinks. Without knowing the exact API it is not possible to tell which implementation the API developers chose. Maybe they were lazy and neither of them.